# VB.Net: Initialising variables with the New constructor

Tags: vb.net, variables, constructor, initialization

When initialising a list or a queue or a stack or anything similar, which method is preferred?

```
Dim q as Queue(Of Integer) = New Queue(Of Integer)
```

or

```
Dim q as New Queue(Of Integer)
```

Also, I've started to use New for string and integer variables - is this stupid? Is there any disadvantage to using New rather than just setting the variable to the default setting? E.g.

```
Dim Num1 As New Integer
Dim Str1 As New String("")
Dim Bool1 As New Boolean
```

Thank you!

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot! Yes, VB.net :).

Comment: Your first method (`Dim q as Queue(Of Integer) = New Queue(Of Integer)`) declares the variable **and** initializes it (to an empty list).  The second method simply declares q but doesn't initialize it (in other words q is `Nothing`).  As for your second question, I've never seen it done that way - I would think a simple `Dim x As <type>` would be sufficient.

Comment: As for which way is better, it depends.  Both are valid.  The first way gives you better protection against Null Reference exceptions, and the second way gives you the option to assign an existing collection to the variable (though you could also do it like this `Dim q As New Queue(Of Integer) = p`, where `p` is another `Queue(Of Integer)`).

Comment: @Tim If I am reading those comments correctly, then `Dim q As New X` and `Dim q As X` are equivalent? That `New` there *seems* like it ought to do something, but I don't use VB ..

Comment: Actually, there is a small difference, but I don't know if it makes a difference in the execution of the program.  It's essentially the same difference between the first two methods OP posted.  `Dim q As New X` declares q **and** creates it (but it's not set to any value), the second one `Dim q As X` simply declares the variable and its type.  I'm not sure if there's any difference in the end...but now you got me curious and I'm going to do a quick test :)

Comment: Ok...quick test done.  For **value** types (like Integer, Boolean, etc) the end result is the same.  `Dim p As Integer` and `Dim p As New Integer()` both result in the variable having the default, uninitialized value (which for Integer is 0).  However, if it was a reference type, simply declaring the variable without using New would result in a Null Reference Exception.  Maybe I should post an example to highlight the differences..

Comment: @LKing Using your first sample there doesn't appear to be any difference where the new keyword is used.  Both ways produce a Queue with count of 0.  However not using the new keyword produces a Queue with a value of Nothing

Comment: @Tim *Does* "..if it was a reference type, simply declaring the variable without using New would result in a Null Reference Exception .." imply that `Dim x As New X()` is equivalent to `Dim x As X = New X()`? In which case, why use one form over the other? Which I believe the question is asking.

Comment: @user2246674 - Yep.  I missed the `As New X()` - I read it as 'As X` - part when I read the question.  In that case, both statements are equivalent and it's a matter of person preference.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd ask programmers whether they like typing more or less when writing a program then the usual answer is "less!".  If you ask them whether they like more or less bugs, the usual answer is "less!"  Those are conflicting goals.

The As New syntax has been part of VB.NET for a very long time.  It however does come with strings attached, you leave it entirely up to the runtime to figure out whether or not a new object should be created.  That does tend to be a bug generator.  Sometimes you really do want to create a new object, even though the variable is already assigned.  It is also rather ambiguous, in this snippet for example:

```
For ix As Integer = 0 To 42
   Dim q As New Queue(Of Integer)
   '' etc...
Next
```

Question is: do you get *one* instance of the queue, created in the first pass of the loop or do you get 43 of them?  What was actually intended by the programmer?  It isn't very clear from the syntax.

There is a 3rd alternative that you overlooked and the one I prefer.  Available since VB9 (aka VS2008) called "type inference".  Where you *don't* specify the type of the variable but leave it up to the compiler to figure it out.  This option needs to be turned on with [Option Infer On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), it is turned on by default.  It combines the advantages of the abbreviated syntax that As New has and still lets you create the object explicitly in your code with the New statement:

```
Option Infer On
...
For ix As Integer = 0 To 42
   Dim q = New Queue(Of Integer)
   '' etc...
Next
```

Where q is inferred to be of type Queue by the compiler and it is crystal clear that the code generates 43 instances of the queue.  The exact equivalent in the C# language is the *var* keyword.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the VB version that type inference was added.